# Apply formatting of symbols from ArcGIS Pro to ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, symbology, arcgis-pro

I have a layer with about 11,000 points. Each point is tied to a point in another layer. The relationship is more or less a parent/children type, where all children tied to a parent is of the same color for their symbology. I am trying to change the outline for all 11,000 points without disrupting the color matching between children and parent points. When I go into the symbol properties and select "Properties for All Symbols", I can change the outline, but then it ends up changing the color of all points to the default monochrome.

An alternative that I've gotten to work is to do the same workflow in ArcGIS Pro by changing the border through the "Properties for All Symbols" which does not change the color and my points end up looking the way I intend. The issue is that I need to publish the service to ArcGIS for Server 10.5, which ArcGIS Pro can not do (only to Portal/AGOL). I was able to publish the two layers from Pro to my Portal and then add them to my ArcMap document as data from AGOL.

Visually, all looks good at the MXD level, but when I publish the MXD as a service to Server 10.5, the layers do not draw correctly, one layer will show, but the other will not. It seems like it's a layer order issue, because it's always the first ordered one that shows in the service and never the second one.

Does anyone know how I can solve this workflow issue or can show me a way that I can either change the symbology in ArcMap or export the layer properties in ArcGIS Pro to import into ArcMap?

Comment: Instead of changing properties for all symbols can you just change symbols for each individual class of points?

Comment: In ArcMap, applying new formatting for all points, or individual classes results in changing the color to the default. In Pro, this process works, but then the issue of Pro --> ArcMap translation arises.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant symbol categories within a feature class. How do you have your points symbolized? What I'm trying to say is don't pick "Properties for all symbols" pick individual symbols instead.

Comment: That would be about 1,700 symbol classes within the total record count of 11,000. That's a lot of clicks for each symbol just to change the outline to a halo or something.

Comment: 1,700 symbol classes strikes me as a lot. Can the end user even distinguish that many colours on the web map? But, regardless of that, could you try removing all symbology classes so only the default one is visible. Symbolize that the way you want. Then click on the add all values button That sometimes adds unique colours for each symbol class added, depending on the type of the original symbol chosen.

Comment: They're not 1,700 unique colors; there may be 15 that get repeated through out the entire extent (U.S.). The point is that when you're looking at a zoomed in area, down to the zip code level, that you see health center A with this color next to health center B with another color, and health center C...etc. The classes were done painstakingly through a manual process before so If I remove the classes and add the values back in, I will lose them. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: It's not very sophisticated, but maybe you could make a dummy layer with the halo and a hollow fill?