# Converting lyrx file or style manager stylx file from ArcGIS Pro to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, layer-file, style-manager

Is there a way to either convert a lyrx file or the style manager stylx file from ArcGIS Pro 2.0 into anything that can be used in ArcMap 10.5?

I have symbology for about 100 items in ArcGIS Pro that I need to be able to use in ArcMap.

Comment: There is an ESRI thread where a workaround was suggested that you upload your ArcGIS Pro projects to ArcGIS Online as a webmap and then download those to ArcMap as an ArcMap package.  See https://community.esri.com/ideas/13650-save-a-layer-lyr-file-from-arcgis-pro and scroll down to jmerson's comment.  Another option is to save symbols with the attribute value name you want to match them with, then ArcMap will apply the symbols automatically.

Comment: Apparently the XTools plugin can allow ArcMap to read .lyrx files directly

Answer (score 4):

There has been a similar question asked as [Apply formatting of symbols from ArcGIS Pro to ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/269231/115), and this may or may not be a duplicate of that.

There is a great deal of complexity available within the symbology of both the ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro applications of ArcGIS Desktop.  With the architecture of ArcGIS Pro being about 20 years newer than that of ArcMap it contains the functionality to read `*.lyr` files, making ArcMap symbology upwardly compatible with ArcGIS Pro.  However, ArcMap cannot read `*.lyrx` files nor can ArcGIS Pro write `*.lyr` files so ArcGIS Pro symbology is not downwardly compatible with ArcMap.

To gain some insight into the complexity of symbology available in ArcGIS Pro perhaps review an ArcPy Help page on [Python CIM access](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) which talks more broadly than just Python.

Answer (score 3):

I just saw by chance, that my ArcMap 10.8.1 was able to import LYRX. I haven't checked if the symbology is complete, but it looks good.

XTools Pro is what allows this to happen in ArcMap

Comment: Hi, that sounds new and interestening. Can you explain a bit more on how you did the import? Just by applying a lyrx-file to a layer in ArcMap, it doesn't seem to work for me so far. Thank you!

Comment: NO !!! I verified with arcmap 10.8.1. It does not work at all.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  Most I can do is change the file extension to lyr so Map can grab it, but that just produces cannot read file error.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could "import" a LYRX to ArcMap was to follow someone's else idea of publishing the layer as a Web Layer from ArcGIS Pro to AGOL and then open it on ArcMap. On my case, ArcMap displayed the symbology correctly and from there I could save a LYR file